# changing specific chars in textbox

Tags: c#, string

i am a noob in here so i might have some mistakes while asking, i apologize from now.
i have a project, in this project i have 3 textboxes. and i need to have the textBox1.Text converted into a int value that i set.

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = "a";
        string b = "b";
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains(a))
        {
            textBox3.Text = a.Replace("a", "1");
        }
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains(b))
        {
            textBox3.Text = b.Replace("b","2");
        }

    }
```

but it just converts it if there is only a or b, not when you enter like `bab` `ab` `aa` `bb` `cab` etc.

i need it to convert *all* a or b chars.

Comment: That's because you use `else if`, it will either do one or the other. Get rid of the `else`. Also String Interpolation (`$`) is not needed here, it can be deleted.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. I'll try and come back here in a min

Comment: there's one more problem, it just replaces the textbox3's text, what i need is converting all a or b's to 1 or 2, but it just converts one of them and stops doing it after 1 char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Contains("a"))
        textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text.Replace("a", "1");

    if (textBox1.Text.Contains("b"))
        textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text.Replace("b", "2");
}
```

What you need to do is call the `Replace()` method on the actual content of the TextBox (`textBox3.Text`) and then store the replaced Text back into the TextBox.

Comment: umm sorry but how do we do that:) i am a noob:)

Comment: oh! now i see, thank you very much! man i can't thank you enough, it just works! You made me so happy right now, hope god makes you happier than me...

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = @"ababa baba aabb";
string pattern = @"a|b";
string x = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, m => m.Value == "a" ? "1" : m.Value == "b" ? "2" : m.Value);
// Output: 12121 2121 1122
```

Comment: yeah that's another way, thnx very much sir.